# ¿Como parseo un comboBox a String?

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Necesito ayuda con el parseo de un comboBox que debo pasarlo a String.
Pero el comboBox que necesito parsear está concatenado en una funcion.

```
public void altaUsuario(String nombre,String apellido,int ci,String mail, String password,TipoUsuario tipoUsuario,Orientacion orient){
    Conn connect = new Conn();
    Connection con = connect.conectarMySQL();
            Statement s;

            try {
                s = con.createStatement();

                s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO usuario (nombre,apellido,mail,ci,password) "+" VALUES('"+nombre+"','"+apellido+"','"+mail+"',"+ci+",'"+password+"');");


                switch(tipoUsuario){

                  case PROFESOR:s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO profesor (ci,**orientacion**)"+" VALUES("+ci+",**"+orient+"**);");



            } catch (SQLException a) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                a.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

//COMIENZA CODIGO DE LA CLASE ORIENTACION
package logica;

public enum Orientacion {
TIC,ADM,ADMYTIC
}
```

Lo que está entre ** ** es lo que necesito parsear

Comment: Necesito parsearlo para que lo registre bien, de la forma en la que se encuentra me tira un error, que es porque no es de tipo string

Comment: ¿El objeto `orientacion` no tiene algún método para obtener el String que quieres, algo como `orientacion.getText()` por ejemplo? Si no lo tienes se lo puedes poner. ¿Podrías mostrar la clase `Orientacion`?

Comment: @A.Cedano En este caso el objeto orientacion no lo tiene porque es un enumerado, ya agrego el codigo de la clase

Comment: ¿Esa es toda la clase? Necesitas en ella un método para obtener el dato.

Comment: Eso lo hago como un getter normal? o como se escribiría?

Comment: Si fueras tan amable de decirme como lo debería escribir te agradezco un montón

Comment: La pregunta, tal como la tienes hasta ahora, no tiene ningún sentido. Primero porque la clase `ComboBox` no es un subtipo de `String`, motivo por el cual no puedes castear un objeto de esta clase a `String` sin que se lance un excepción en tiempo de ejecución. Además, luego indicas que el tipo `Orientacion` no es un subtipo de `ComboBox` sino que es un enumerado. Te recomiendo que cambies el título y parte del cuerpo de la pregunta para que se ajuste al problema planteado.

Comment: Los enumerados en java, como cualquier otro objeto, se concatenan con los `String`s sin problemas. El error debe estar en otra parte. Podrías compartir la traza completa?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @E.Betanzos porque el enum si lo concatenas te retorna el valor String que haya sido seleccionado que seria uno de estos 3 TIC ADM ADMYTIC. Si hay una traza de error siempre hay que agregarla en la pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo logre use la funcion .name() y lo concatene de la siguiente manera (' "+orient.name()+ " ' )